# An integrally defined borel measurable function

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow (0, \infty)$ be a Borel measurable function and let $E$ be a Borel measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\lambda (E) > 0$. Define $F(t) = \int_{E}f(t + x) d \lambda (x)$, $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Prove that $F$ is a Borel measurable. Prove further that if $F \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$, then $f \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\lambda (E) < \infty$.

We can write $f(s) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}\chi_{F_{i}}(s)$, where $F_{i}$ are pairwise disjoint Borel sets and $a_{i}$ are positive real numbers. Then $F(t) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}\lambda (E \cap (F_{i} - t))$. I think this is the point where I need to invoke $\lambda (E) > 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\phi(t,x)=1_E(x)f(t-x)$. Then $\phi\in L^+(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R})$ (it is nonnegative and measurable w.r.t the product $\sigma$-algebra) and by (Fubini-)Tonelli theorem $F(t)=\int \phi_td\lambda$ is measurable (if $\lambda(E)=0$, then $F\equiv 0$ so that it's trivially measurable).

As for the second part, by (Fubini-)Tonelli again and translation invariance of the Lebesgue integral,
$$
\int F=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_Ef(t+x)d\lambda(x)d\lambda(t)=\int_E\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(t+x)d\lambda(t)d\lambda(x)\\ =\int_E\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(t)d\lambda(t)d\lambda(x)=\int f\times \lambda(E)< \infty.
$$

Comment: would you elaborate more on the first part of the question?

Comment: @stat_yale What exactly is not clear?

Comment: I’m quite beginner in real analysis so some are not immediate for me. 1)we want to prove that $F(t)$ is borel measurable that is stronger than measurability. 2)how would fubini gives us that?

Comment: What do u mean by the second (weaker) "measurability"?

Comment: so I know that not every measurable function is borel measurable. Unless , in the above question, they are equivalent.

Comment: 1. Measurability of a function involves 2 $\sigma$-algebras corresponding to the domain and the range of that function, i.e. a function $f$ from $(X,\mathcal{N})$ to $(Y,\mathcal{M})$ is $(\mathcal{N},\mathcal{M})$-measurable if $f^{-1}(A)\in \mathcal{M}$ for all $A\in \mathcal{N}$.

Comment: 2. When it's clear from the context the reference to underlying $\sigma$-algebras is typically omitted. In our case the OP explicitly asked to show that $F$ is Borel measurable that is $(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}_{>0}))$-measurable.

Comment: 3. Look at Theorem 7.7 in [these notes](https://www.math.cuhk.edu.hk/course_builder/1617/math5012/Real%20Analysis_Chapter_7.2017.pdf) for the complete statement of Fubini's theorem.