# Show that $ F(t) = \int_E f(t + x)d\lambda(x)$ is Borel measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, borel-measures

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to (0,\infty)$ be a Borel measurable function and let $E$ be a Borel measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\lambda(E)>0$ . Denote
$ F(t) = \int_E f(t + x)d\lambda(x), t \in \mathbb{R}. $

Prove that $F$ is Borel measurable.

Prove that if $F \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, then $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $\lambda(E) < \infty.$

This question is asked similary in the below links but as of the first part I could not understand how to prove the borel measurability. I'm quite a begginer in real analysis, so I was wondering if someone can help by through a step by step understanding of the proofs suggested in the links.

---

links:
[Link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3200628/prove-that-gx-int-01fx-ydy-is-borel-measurable?rq=1) , [link2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773582/an-integrally-defined-borel-measurable-function)

Comment: I believe you have a typo..you  want to integrate over $E$ not $R$

Comment: yes, I corrected it

Comment: You will want to use the translation-invariance of Lebesgue measure, i.e. $\lambda(E) = \lambda(E+t)$ for $t\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Math1000 I was wondering to have something more than just hint or the goal of the question to understand the proofs

Comment: It seems to me that the Lebesgue integral of measurable function should be measurable but a proof of that fact is escaping me at the moment.

Comment: Apply the usual way: start with $f$ the indicator of a measurable set and then pass to the general case by limits and monotone convergence.

Comment: HINT: point-wise limit of measurable functions is measurable